# Speed up RDS printing

Tags: terminal-server, printing, rds

We've recently moved our clients from a Server 2003 terminal server using ThinPrint .print to Windows Server 2008 R2 RDS via a RDS Gateway using Easy Print.

We've got some clients in Indonesia on crappy ISDN links who are saying that printing is now taking a lot, lot longer over RDS than it used to over ThinPrint.

I'm guessing that ThinPrint somehow spools to a buffer, compresses it, transfers it, and then *then* prints it, where as RDS is doing something different.

Are there any tips and tricks to getting RDS printing sped up? Or do we now have to go and fork out another few grand on more ThinPrint licenses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the basic operation of Easy Print is such: the client sends information about the printer (options, accessories, etc.) in the form of XML/XPS to the server, which then uses the Easy Print feature to encapsulate the print job in to an XPS spool file and sends that file to the client for rendering. Microsoft claims that this requires less bandwidth and makes the printing process faster for the client, but I'm skeptical. There is a hotfix (for a hotfix) that may apply in your case:

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=954743

Comment: :o this hotfix is due to another really, really irritating (but less critical) problem we were having, according to the blurb - printing in the wrong orientation

Comment: Well hopefully it resolves both issues.

Comment: Update: Turns out this is only for their XP computers with specific versions of .net installed. Their Windows 7 PC's are fine. So we told them that it's out of our control and to get Windows 7 PC's. The link you provided put me on the right path and was the same issue, but different symptoms.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out.

Answer (score 2):

Using windows 2008 Easy Print we found what happens  that the server produced XPS file is quite bloated and it a longer time to move over to the client queue On the client if you are using an older printer driver that does not support XPS windows does a XPS to GDI conversion before printing. All this adds up and slows down bulk printing due slow transfers of bulky XPS files to the client and subsequent XPS to GDI conversions at the clinet.